# Keep collaborated forked remote up to date with master

Tags: git, rebase

Normally, I work on my own forked repo and keep it up to date with regular

```
git pull --rebase upstream develop
```

and pushing the update along with my commits to my origin (forked from upstream), and later raise a PR after development.

But now, I have a collaborator in my `origin/develop`.
So if one person pushes the commits to above branch, another has to rebase it, then commit.

Also, to keep the draft PR reviewable, I have to rebase my `develop` locally, then push them to `origin`

Problem is, I am ending up with duplicate empty merge commits. And I feel like I am not doing it in right sequence.

Can someone point out the operations in right sequence?

Once again, branches are:

```
upstream/develop
  -> origin/develop [fork]
    -> develop [local, Raj]
    -> develop [local, Deep]
```

Appreciate your support.

Comment: Why do you get merge commits if you are rebasing?

Comment: Someone might have used Github Desktop which pulls and then merges, rather than rebase. But what should be the right order? 
Say someone has added their commit in origin, then should I be doing 
git pull rebase of master into local, then 
git pull rebase of remote origin into local
then push to origin
Or, interchange the rebase sequence above and push to origin?